# Javascript keeps printing the same date/time and doesn't update

Tags: javascript

[Cash Register App I'm Making(log on upper right corner)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UykN9.png)

I am making a simple cash register web app that calculates and logs manual item input. My java script function executes onclick and adds to the HTML log the date time info it was clicked on. But the correct date/time is only logged the first time, the next ones are a repetition of the first. No update.

variables example below

```
var now=new Date();
var profit=0;
var month=now.getMonth()+1;
var day= function(){return now.getDate();};
var year=function(){return now.getFullYear();};
var hour=function(){return now.getHours();};
var minute=function(){return now.getMinutes();};
var seconds=function(){return now.getSeconds();};
```

Function Sample

```
document.getElementById("log").innerHTML+="<tr>"+"<td>"+month+"/"+day()+"/"+year()+"</td>"+"<td>"+
hour()+":"+minute()+":"+seconds()+"</td>"+"<td>"+"$"+last+"</td>"+"</tr>";
```

Comment: The variables are only given values once, when you initialize them. They're not updated automatically every time you use them. If you need them updated, declare them in the function scope and set them there, or declare them in a broader scope and write a function that updates them, and then call that function just before you're going to use the variables to update them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are not updated automatically, you need to use functions, something like:

```js
(function() {
  function getDate() {
    let _now = new Date();
    return {
      month: _now.getMonth() + 1,
      day: _now.getDate(),
      year: _now.getFullYear(),
      hour: _now.getHours(),
      minute: _now.getMinutes(),
      seconds: _now.getSeconds()
    }
  }

  let log = document.getElementById("log");

  function clearLog() {
    log.innerHTML = "";
  }

  function changeLog() {
    let newDate = getDate(),
      last = "{{ last }}";

    log.innerHTML += "<tr>" + "<td>" + newDate.month + "/" + newDate.day + "/" + newDate.year + "</td>" + "<td>" +
      newDate.hour + ":" + newDate.minute + ":" + newDate.seconds + "</td>" + "<td>" + "$" + last + "</td>" + "</tr>";
  }

  function _initEvents() {
    document.getElementById('get-log').addEventListener('click', function() {
      clearLog();
      changeLog();
    });
  }

  _initEvents();

})();
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
<button id="get-log">Get Log</button>
```

And just call:

Answer (score 4):

The variable 'now' is declared and set at the start, and then referenced by subsequent functions.  In order to update you would have to call the 'new Date()' method inside each function, instead of just referencing the variable as previously declared.

Comment: var now = function () { return new Date(); };